# Generic methods in interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface which basically does POST requests

```
public interface IRestService
    {
        T Post<T>(string path, string payLoad) where T : class;
        string Post(string path, string payLoad);
    }
```

Is there a way, i can combine these two Post methods into one. 
The first Post will deserailize the response string into a class
The second Post is just to return the response as a string.

Comment: You can't have one method with two different return types.

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't just call `Post<string>(...)` to get it to return the response as a string? You may need to include extra logic to do that though

Comment: It is not a problem.  Merely awkward in the code that uses the interface, it must explicitly use, say, `Post<object>(...)` with the named parameter type not optional.

Comment: @ZacFaragher: It's a clever idea, but I imagine the inconsistency of method behavior based on the type parameter wouldn't be worth whatever the user is trying to save.  I wonder what actual problem the OP is trying to solve here.  If the methods are confusing in their current form then simply renaming them could clear that up.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this interface. You just need to explicitly call the `Post` method with the generic type when you want to call the generic method rather than the one that returns `string`.

Comment: @ZacFaragher, tats how i have implemented now, made this to return just the string and am deserailizing into object in my class, I thought there would be a way to combine these methods

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem and it can be overcome by encapsulating the returned value in another class. I am guessing the second one `string Post` is to return an error message. If that's the case you can do something like this:

```
public class Response<T> where T : class {
    T data;
    string message;
    int statusCode //another field that would make error checking easier
}

public interface IRestService
{
    Response<T> Post<T>(string path, string payLoad) where T : class;
}
```

Comment: Am not using another post to send an error message, one of my API returns a JSON string, and another its just a plain string. For now, I have changed my implementation to use only one post method to return a string, and am doing the de-serialization on my class, but i was guessing i could i could combine the POST to return a class or a string based on the response

Comment: You can still do it in a similar way, for instance if string is null, you can use the class and vice versa. Or infer from the status code. Or check if string can be serialized or not.